# Need help resolving SQL Server error - 'Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.'

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to modify a script originally written for MySQL to use with SQL Server 2014. While I understand the idea behind the error, I don't have any idea as to how to fix it. Since most questions I've seen involve casting to or from numeric and this has neither, I'm not sure where to start.

The query is looking at a database of zip codes with latitudes and longitudes to determine the zip codes with a certain radius (10 in this case).

```
select * 
from tbl_zipCodes AS z 
where 
    (SQRT((69.172 * (33.029167000000001 - z.latitude)) * (69.172 * (33.029167000000001 - z.latitude)) + (53.0 *(-97.068675999999996 - z.longitude)) * (53.0 *(-97.068675999999996 - z.longitude))) <= 10 )
```

Many thanks in advance for any tips or assistance - I'll be happy to provide any additional information required.

---

Here is a simplified version of the schema:

```
id      int     NOT NULL PK
zipCode     varchar(25) Checked
latitude    varchar(500)    Checked
longitude   varchar(500)    Checked
active  bit Checked
```

And Sample data for zip code 75028.  This is the data that is generating the error, so it should be reproducable

```
76051   32.935290000000002  -97.068689000000006 1
76092   32.951594   -97.150991000000005 1
76205   33.188906000000003  -97.127021999999997 1
76210   33.145139999999998  -97.088560000000001 1
76226   33.115116   -97.162499999999994 1
76262   33.010711000000001  -97.216288000000006 1
75007   33.003920999999998  -96.895926000000003 1
75010   33.029434000000002  -96.897384000000002 1
75019   32.960099999999997  -96.982656000000006 1
75022   33.02861    -97.121368000000004 1
75056   33.072392000000001  -96.907000999999994 1
75057   33.047165999999997  -96.983309000000006 1
75063   32.919516999999999  -96.977421000000007 1
75065   33.115397999999999  -97.004728999999998 1
75067   33.01972    -96.991410000000002 1
75028   33.029167000000001  -97.068675999999996 1
75077   33.078944999999997  -97.077551999999997 1
75358   32.937800000000003  -96.790800000000004 1
```

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: What are the types of the `latitude` and `longitude` columns?

Comment: The latitude and longitude columns are of type VARCHAR or NVARCHAR I'm assuming. Can you edit your question and add some sample rows in `tbl_zipCodes`? PS: hungarian notation is discouraged, [especially for table names](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/154251/65699).

Comment: You're right - the lat and long are varchar.  I've included the table schema and a data set that is causing the error.  This is part of a query that came from http://www.zipcodestogo.com/lookups/radius-search.php and this data is what should be coming back when searching for zip codes within 10 miles of 75028.  Ultimately, I need to take the returned zip codes and search another table to pull a list of available events in a given area - but first things first.